# Do I need to upgrade Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Tags: 20.04, upgrade

I see that Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS has been marked as end of life for January 2022. I am guessing that the LTS in the title means I should be good to continue using this version, but am curious if there are any actions that I should be taking?

Thank you in advance for any advice!

Comment: Where is it "marked as end of life for January 2022"?

Comment: February 24th 2022 PointRelease Ubuntu 20.04.4 https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseSchedule .......... End of Standard Support = Apr 2025

Comment: EoSS for 20.04 LTS is 2025: https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle

Comment: LTS (Long Term Support) releases have 5 year support lifetimes. But you should upgrade your system before the deadline. EOL systems don't get most software updates, and are NOT supported on AskUbuntu.

Comment: @Pilot6 I was going of the Ubuntu kernel release cycle: https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle
A quick google search showed a table listing EOL as 2022, but after navigating to the site it looks to be 2025. Maybe some nuance there I'm not getting?

Comment: Point releases 20.04.X are incremental updates to the system, typically released 6 months apart. However, the End of Support or End of Life dates do not change because of this.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.4 upgrades are rolling out to 20.04.3 boxes already.  The 20.04.3 kernel was 5.11, but I bet you're already using the 5.13 kernel from 20.04.4 (*originally from 21.10*) even though your `lsb_release` details may still say you're on 20.04.3 ... ie. your system is upgrading itself as long as you're performing `sudo apt full-upgrade` regularly, even if you've not got all of 20.04.4 upgrades (*which will include changing version number when all are installed*)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I... think you're a little confused here and have misinformation.

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS has a 5 year support cycle.  It reaches the End of Standard Support in 2025.  This is listed on the [Ubuntu Releases](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) page of the Ubuntu wiki that gives the list of Ubuntu releases and when they're supported to under Standard Support.

You have until 2025 to decide to upgrade your 20.04 boxes.

Any other information that is not from the Ubuntu wiki or on the Ubuntu Announcements mailing list is not properly sourced and misinformation.

Comment: As I mentioned in an earlier comment... the discrepancy resulted from the google feature that displays data tables in search results, listing EOL for this particular version as 2022. You can try yourself if your interested.

Anyways... thanks for the info, have a good one

Comment: @BuckleysAngel I would suggest you mark this as the accepted answer since this answers the question you had about the EOL status.  And to just mark the question as resolved.